# Convert a type struct A to B

Tags: go

I want to convert Struct A to B but I didn’t found a simple and good approach for this problem

```
   type Bob struct {
      Name string 
      Age int 
   }

   type Mark struct {
      Name string 
      Age int 
      HairColor string 
   }
```

any ideas? I don’t want to write a assign statement for all properties like

```
Mark{
Name:bob.Name, 
Age: bob.Age,
}
```

Because this approach get's very tedious if a Struct A and B have a lot of properties like 20

The solution should also handle deeply nested structs

Edit: sometimes the underlying structure isn’t equal of both structs like A has more properties like B or vice versa

Comment: I think you should change your question a little to show that the types are not necessarily actually identical.The answer is very different in that case.

Comment: I changed my question a bit. Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general, low-level way to achieve this in Go is by using reflection. You can look up the names of the fields and set the values appropriately. However I would recommend using a library, such as https://github.com/jinzhu/copier for deep copying. Otherwise you'll find it gets quite hairy with different types such as pointers and slices.

You can simply do: `copier.Copy(&mark, &bob)` (where mark and bob are instances of Mark and Bob structs, obviously).

Answer (score 3):

Because `Mark` and `Bob` have the same underlying type, a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) can be used to to convert between the two types. Here's how to convert a `Bob` to a `Mark`:

```
b := Bob{Name: "Bob", Age: 22}
m := Mark(b)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0FNA4MM8_1w).

Edit: OP changed the question. Updated answer follows.

Use the reflect package to copy the subset of matching fields from one struct to the other:

```
// copyCommonFields copies the common fields from the struct
// pointed to srcp to the struct pointed to by destp.
func copyCommonFields(destp, srcp interface{}) {
    destv := reflect.ValueOf(destp).Elem()
    srcv := reflect.ValueOf(srcp).Elem()

    destt := destv.Type()
    for i := 0; i < destt.NumField(); i++ {
        sf := destt.Field(i)
        v := srcv.FieldByName(sf.Name)
        if !v.IsValid() || !v.Type().AssignableTo(sf.Type) {
            continue
        }
        destv.Field(i).Set(v)
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
b := Bob{Name: "Bob", Age: 22, ShoeSize: 9}
var m Mark
copyCommonFields(&m, &b)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NFbQDYQyFQR).

Comment: If the underlying structure isn’t completely same then it isn’t anymore possible

Comment: Sorry my question was a bit unprecise. I changed my question maybe you have a answer for this as well

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to put the common fields in a separate struct and embed that in the other structs:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

type Bob struct {
    Person
}

type Mark struct {
    Person
    HairColor string
}
```

Then you can create a `Mark` object with

```
Mark{
    Person: bob.Person,
    // other initializations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If first fields are the same and you aren't squeamish about using unsafe, then here's the fastest one line solution:

https://play.golang.org/p/gqlq-vLsLXE